# What is the best way to store user notes locally for a UWP notes app?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I'm working on a simple light-weight notes app that will allow a user to simply store quick notes, and maybe even tag notes. I would like to actually know what is the best way to LOCALLY store these notes. Also, at some point I may also allow for the user to do a few more advanced things, like style the text, so the way I store the data needs to be flexible enough to deal with this, too.

At a later time I will implement a way for the user to save this data in the cloud (OneDrive), but that's not the big matter here. Thanks!

Is it me, or Microsoft doesn't provide any OFFICIAL documentation that lists and details storage options for UWP apps? It would have been nice to see a list of these options so that we could then take it upon ourselves to do some detailed research on them and make a decision for what we should use based on that. Seems like you have to dig deep into the web to ascertain what's available and MOST compatible with their latest operating system.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [Create, write, and read a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185401.aspx).

Actually, there are official documents for UWP development, you can refer to [How-to guides for Windows 10 apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt244352.aspx).

This [Files, folders, and libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185399.aspx) chapter details storage file, folder of UWP.

More even, there a lots of [Universal Windows app samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) on GitHub, there are several samples here about storage.

Noticed that you want to store the notes after style them, you will need to serialize them to string format before storing, and deserialize them after you read them from file.

The [XmlSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can help you with serializing and deserializing, you can also refer to the official [Serializing and deserializing data sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DataReaderWriter).

And there is no "best way", it's all up to your need.

Comment: Does this data serializing need to be used with database storage? Surely, I can't save styled text into a database text field so what exactly needs to be done for that if I'm to use a database for storage?

Comment: Have you tried anything for now? It depends on what database you want to use. Data serializing need to be used with any database doesn't support storing a Object, for this scenario, for example you need to serialize this object to string.

Answer (score 1):

The best method would be using Sqlite create a database write the notes in this database with timestamp, username etc. and store this database in local storage.
If you just need to simply save what user had written you can write to a text file in local storage.if you dont want to write simple code. Though finding required notes later would be difficult

Comment: Thanks for the input. And yes it would be hell to retrieve that data in a structured manner (when using text files). So far the database seems to make the most sense, but I'll do a little more research to be sure I have exactly what I need.The last thing I need is to finish the project and later learn that it would have made more sense to use a different approach to storing data, once I add new features. Thanks again.

Comment: If your data is limited then you can directly store inside Local storage. But if you want to create a decent app then sqlite is the answer. If you do find any other method(though I highly doubt it) pls dont forget to post it here and Mark it Answered so that it can help others.